# Bootstrap validation without form tag in asp.net for particular button

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, validation

In single page for two different buttons, Bootstrap validation **without form tag** in asp.net for particular buttons. Similar to like validation group.. Is there any way?

Comment: use javascript function.

Comment: Yes that's true but i want to use bootstrap validation .

Comment: without form tag you cannot validate. Have a look at this it may be helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317193/jquery-validation-against-twitter-bootstrap-button-group

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do a trick for this...

```
1) Identify the classes that is applied on validate
2) Write a script to validate on click event for particular button
```

your script will be like

```
$("#btnId").click(function(){

   var IsValid=true;
   if($("#txtName").val()=="")
   {
       IsValid=false;          
       //Apply the classes that you have identified
       $("#txtName").attr("class","className");          

   }
   else
   {
     //Apply normal class 
     $("#txtName").attr("class","className");     
   }


   if(IsValid)
   {
     return True;
   } 
   else
   {
     return False;
   }


});
```

this is only idea so don't look out the syntax.....
may this help

Answer (score 0):

use customize `jQuery` on each button's Click

```
$('.login').on('click', LoginFunction);
$('.register').on('click', RegisterFunction);


function LoginFunction() {
    var valid = true,
    errorMessage = "";
    if ($('#Login').val() == '') {
       errorMessage  = "please enter your Login \n";
       valid = false;
    }


    if ($('#Password').val() == '') {
       errorMessage += "please enter your PAssword\n";
       valid = false;
    } 

    if( !valid && errorMessage.length > 0){
       alert(errorMessage);
    }   

}



function  RegisterFunction() {
    var valid = true,
    errorMessage = "";

    if ($('#name').val() == '') {
       errorMessage  = "please enter your name \n";
       valid = false;
    }

    if ($('#address').val() == '') {
       errorMessage += "please enter your address\n";
       valid = false;
    }    

    if ($('#email').val() == '') {
       errorMessage += "please enter your email\n";
       valid = false;
    } 

    if( !valid && errorMessage.length > 0){
       alert(errorMessage);
    }   


}
```